# limer log in "Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file."

Tags: r, limesurvey

I'm using the package `limer` to fetch the data from Limesurvey. When I use the function get_session_key after defining the username, password, and API, I get the following error:

```
Error: Argument 'txt' must be a JSON string, URL or file.
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please share info on `txt` using `dput`

Comment: Do you mean? `dput(txt)`?

Comment: Yes exactly, to get the content `txt`

Comment: Solved. I tried to reinstall Limesurvey, and it worked. Nevertheless, thanks, Clemsang.